# My axios API request works on Postman, but not on the web

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, axios

I'm using an express server and setting these headers:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});
```

When I run this api call on Postman, I get a success:
[image]

I run into problems when I try to do this on the web.

I am creating an axios instance like so:
    import axios from "axios";

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.1.9:9000"
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      config.headers["token"] = token;
    }
    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    return config;
  },
  err => Promise.reject(err)
);

export default instance;
```

In my web app I am calling the api, but the 'token' and 'Content-Type' headers are not showing up there:

```
axiosInstance.get("/api/admin/users").then(response => {
  console.log("response::::", response);
});
```

[image]

How do I get the token and Content-Type headers to go through?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the browser sending an `OPTIONS` request as well? You might have to enable `OPTIONS` CORS requests on your server.